# Phing String Manipulation

Tags: phing

I have a Phing project that you pass in a parameter. I want to perform simple string manipulation on this parameter such a strtolower() or ucwords() etc. Any ideas how I can go about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about using the PhpEvaLTask:

```
<project name="StringTest" default="all" basedir=".">
<target name="stringtest"  description="test">
    <php expression="strtolower(${param})" returnProperty="paramToLower"/>
    <php expression="ucwords(${param})" returnProperty="paramUcwords"/>
    <echo>To lower ${paramToLower}</echo>
    <echo>UcWords ${paramUcwords}</echo>
</target>
```

Running it with:

```
phing -Dparam=BLAH stringtest
```

Yields:

```
Buildfile: /export/users/marcelog/build.xml
```

StringTest > stringtest:

```
  [php] Evaluating PHP expression: strtolower(BLAH)
  [php] Evaluating PHP expression: ucwords(BLAH)
 [echo] To lower blah
 [echo] UcWords BLAH
```

BUILD FINISHED

Comment: Helped a lot, But there is bug: `strtolower(${param})` should be `strtolower('${param}')` (missing '). Your example will crash on: `phing stringtest -Dparam="a b.c"`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this:

```xml
<php function="strtolower" returnProperty="paramToLower">
    <param value="${param}" />
</php>

<php function="ucwords" returnProperty="paramUcwords">
    <param value="${param}" />
</php>
```