# Compute property arithmetically

Tags: jenkins, deployment, phing

In short I am not able to make a computation based on a property within my build file.

Let's say I have:

`<property name="basedir" value="${project.basedir}" />` <--Current value `73`

***How can I know the previous 3 builds (`72,71` and `70`) OR how can I compute these values(based on the basedir property)?***

I have tried (ignore the addition):

1. `<property name="basedir" value="${project.basedir}+1" />` <--But it concats the value: `73+1`
2. `<property name="basedir" value="${project.basedir+1}" />` <--But it is just wrong: `build_${env.BUILD_NUMBER+1}`

**Scenario**: Remove old releases (keep some releases in case of a rollback)

**P.S:** The duplicate link is invalid because this is a deployment via **PHING** not **ANT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [adhoc-task](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/app.coretasks.html#AdhocTaskdefTask) for this:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <project default="main" phingVersion="2.11.0">
  <property name="basedir" value = "73"/>
  <adhoc-task name="increment"><![CDATA[
  class increment extends Task {
      private $value;

      function setvalue($value) {
          $this->value = $value;
      }
     function setProperty($property) {
         $this->property = $property;
      }

     function main() {
         $this->project->setProperty($this->property, ((int) $this->value + 1));
      }
  }
  ]]></adhoc-task>
  <target name="main">
  <echo>${basedir}</echo>
  <increment value="${basedir}" property="basedir"/>
  <echo>${basedir}</echo>
  </target>
  </project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, good for more complex things. Found an easier way by using php expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432771/phing-string-manipulation

Comment: That's great :-) I have to admit, I may have been showing off a bit... :D